# Ajax jQuery issue in IE 9 in Ember JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, ember.js

My below code working on Chrome and Mozilla but in IE9+ version it is not working.
I am using Ember JS.

```
$.ajax({
    type:        "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    url:         OrgPortalENV.ABC.API_URL + "/test",
    data:        JSON.stringify( jsonPayload )
})
// Received an HTTP 200 OK response
.done(
    function(data) {
        alert("done");
    },
    $.proxy(ABCAjax.handleHttpOkResponse, this)
)
// Received an HTTP 4XX or 5XX error response
.fail(
    function(jqXHR, data) {
        alert("fail");
        // End the nice loading animation
    },
    $.proxy(ABCAjax.handleHttpErrorResponse, this)
);
```

Comment: I know IE was very sensitive so I follow proper order of Ajax function 
with different combination but still not working

Comment: dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml"
                 or
dataType:    ($.browser.msie) ? "Json" : "xml"
                 or
dataType:    ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "Json"

Comment: cache: true,
async: true,
crossDomain: true,
dataType: "json"

Comment: I have try with in that code and finally decide that some problem in
URL parameter  in IE 9 .